# Is there a way to mock jdbcTemplate of spring using JMockit?

Tags: jmockit

I'm writing unit test cases using JMockit for DAOs in my application for which I have to mock the jdbcTemplate of spring so that there will not be any call to the database. I have seen other posts/examples talking about mocking the DAO but never found something that talks about mocking jdbcTemplate. Is there a way I could mock it and if there is one where do I start?

Answer (score 0):

You should mock de DataSource element wich is the one external, also if you check in JDBCTemplate code it execute sentence getting a connection wich is adquired from the DataSource..so you should give a mocked Connection thought the mocked DataSource which gives U what U want in every execution.